# How do I change extension file in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to change extension of some of my file.
I tried this code, but it still return error

```
The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed.
```

Anyone can help please?

```
 $b = "TA"
 $c = "70"
 $Path_1 = "C:\Users\hh\Documents"
 $Found = Get-ChildItem -Name "$Path_1\*$b-$c*.txt" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('.txt','.csv') }
```

Comment: What is the complete error message?  What does `get-childitem -name` output?

Comment: i _think_ you need to convert the scriptblock braces surrounding the `.Replace()` call with priority-of-execution parens to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of the error message is "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression".  "get-childitem -name" only outputs a string, not an object with properties.  Take out the -name after get-childitem, and it would work.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$b = "TA"
 $c = "70"
 $Path_1 = "C:\Users\hh\Documents"
 $Found = Get-ChildItem -Filter ($Path_1 + "\*" + $b + "-" + $c + "*.txt")
foreach ($entry in $Found){
  Rename-Item -Path $entry.FullName -NewName ($entry.Name.Replace('.txt','.csv'))
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do `.Replace()` to avoid files having a double extension like `TA-70.txt.txt` to become `TA-70.csv.csv`. If you do want to use replace, use the Regex `-replace` with an anchor. Something like `-replace '\.txt$', '.csv'`

Comment: I think, this seems to be a theoretical problem in this case. The script assumes there is a folder with a lot of files with a only one .txt at the end. And even if there are more of them, it doesn't seem to make a big problem here.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is much easier to use both the `-Path` and `-Filter` parameters on the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet.
If you want to make sure you do not by accident change folder names, in PowerShell version 3.0 and up, add the `-File` switch aswell like I'm doing here:

```
$b = "TA"
$c = "70"
$Path_1 = "C:\Users\hh\Documents"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path_1 -Filter "*$b-$c*.txt" | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}.csv' -f $_.BaseName } -WhatIf
# For PowerShell versions below 3.0, you need to add an extra Where-Object clause:
# Get-ChildItem -Path $Path_1 -Filter "*$b-$c*.txt" | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}.csv' -f $_.BaseName } -WhatIf
```

Of course, you can also use .NET [System.IO.Path]

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path_1 -Filter "*$b-$c*.txt" | Rename-Item -NewName { [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, ".csv") } -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch if you are satisfied with the results.